# tokenize C++ program in python

Tags: python, stringtokenizer

I need to tokenize the C++ file for my project. For that, I am using tokenize.generate_tokens. In each line I get a weird char because of '\r' and it is parsed as a token. I need to avoid that character to count the token. I am not sure how to do that when I passing the file to tokenize. below is my code I am using:

```
f = open("BM1A1.cpp","r")
g = tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline)
```

I tried strip() but gives give error

```
g = tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline.strip())
error:
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: This is not the particular issue you're having right now, but you'll later find out that `tokenize.generate_tokens` is for Python source code, not C++ source code.

Comment: Might want to check out [this link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang).

Answer (score 2):

Since `generate_tokens` require callable as input argument, you need to create your custom function.

> The `generate_tokens()` generator requires one argument, `readline`, which must be a **callable** object which provides the same interface as the readline() method of built-in file objects (see section File Objects). Each call to the function should return one line of input as a string.Alternately, readline may be a callable object that signals completion by raising StopIteration.

Easiest way is to create a lambda:

```
f = open("BM1A1.cpp","r")
g = tokenize.generate_tokens(lambda: f.readline().strip())
```

Obviously, you'll encounter weird result of parsing, because `tokenize` module is defined for Python syntax, not C++ syntax.

Comment: It is only going through one line does not tokenize after that.

Comment: have you consumed generator? `list(g)` will give you list of tokens. Or you may iterate over them via `for token in g:` idiom.

Comment: Yes, I did that.It only print this :  #include <iostream>

using
namespace
std
;